# Resizing of a div in an other div on resizing of the page

Tags: html, css

I would like to resize my div that is in another div that has to be more little than the master div.

I wrote this jsfiddle to make you understand.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5YukJ/492/)

[Jsfiddle whit div.resize in % height](http://jsfiddle.net/5YukJ/493/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="resize">
  <div class="red">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container
{
    width:800px;
    height:500px;
}
html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%
}
.resize{
  height:200px;
}

.red{
background-color: red;
height: 50%;
}
```

I can't understand why, if I resize the page and also the div "resize", the div "red" doesn't resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working just fine. Added some outlines so you can see the edges.

The `.red` div is half the height of its parent. Change the parent and you'll see the `.red` div change its height.

Also, resizing the browser window should not have any effect, since you are setting the `.container` and the `.resize` to fixed pixel values.

```css
html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100% /* Not needed, this is the default */
}

.container {
  width:600px;
  height:150px;
  outline:1px solid black;
}

.resize{
  height:100px;
  outline:1px solid aqua;
}

div.red{
  background-color: red; 
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="resize">
  <div class="red"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

But, if you are looking for automatic resizing, you can't use fixed values (pixels), you must use relative values (percents, vh, vw, em), like this:

```css
.container {
  width:600px;
  height:10vh; /* 10% the height of the viewport */
  outline:1px solid black;
}

.resize{
  height:75%; /* 75% the height of the parent element */
  outline:1px solid aqua;
}

div.red{
  background-color: red; 
  height: 50%; /* 50% the height of the parent */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="resize">
  <div class="red"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I make that when I resize the page it resizes?

Comment: Sure it does. The `.red` div is exactly half the height of its parent. Change the parent, and `.red` resizes. This is what you get when you work with fixed values. If you want it to automatically resize, stop using pixels and use relative values.

Comment: I don't understand. can you make me an example with maybe a jsfiddle? I would like the resizing of the red when the age resize.

Comment: @NiccolòGuidi See my updated answer. If you want resizing based on browser resizing, you can't use a fixed size (600px), you have to use relative units. Percentages are always based on the parent element. You had a parent element that had a fixed size (600px), so the child was always going to be 50% of that (300px).